# Elasticsearch Completion Suggester doesn't return documents on searches that match input

Tags: elasticsearch, completion

I have a weird problem with Elasticsearch 6.0.

I have an index with the following mapping:

```
{
  "cities": {
    "mappings": {
      "cities": {
        "properties": {
          "city": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "name": {
                "properties": {
                  "en": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "it": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "slug": {
                "properties": {
                  "en": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "it": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "doctype": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "suggest": {
            "type": "completion",
            "analyzer": "accents",
            "search_analyzer": "simple",
            "preserve_separators": true,
            "preserve_position_increments": false,
            "max_input_length": 50
          },
          "weight": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have these documents in my index:

```
{
  "_index": "cities",
  "_type": "cities",
  "_id": "991-city",
  "_version": 128,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "doctype": "city",
    "suggest": {
      "input": [
        "nazaré",
        "nazare",
        "나자레",
        "najare",
        "najale",
        "ナザレ",
        "Ναζαρέ"
      ],
      "weight": 1807
    },
    "weight": 3012,
    "city": {
      "id": 991,
      "name": {
        "en": "Nazaré",
        "it": "Nazaré"
      },
      "slug": {
        "en": "nazare",
        "it": "nazare"
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "_index": "cities",
  "_type": "cities",
  "_id": "1085-city",
  "_version": 128,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "doctype": "city",
    "suggest": {
      "input": [
        "nazareth",
        "nazaret",
        "拿撒勒",
        "na sa le",
        "sa le",
        "le",
        "na-sa-lei",
        "나사렛",
        "nasares",
        "nasales",
        "ナザレス",
        "nazaresu",
        "नज़ारेथ",
        "nj'aareth",
        "aareth",
        "najaratha",
        "Назарет",
        "Ναζαρέτ",
        "názáret",
        "nazaretas"
      ],
      "weight": 1809
    },
    "weight": 3015,
    "city": {
      "id": 1085,
      "name": {
        "en": "Nazareth",
        "it": "Nazareth"
      },
      "slug": {
        "en": "nazareth",
        "it": "nazareth"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when I search using the suggester, with the following query:

```
POST /cities/_search
{
  "suggest":{
    "suggest":{
      "prefix":"nazare",
      "completion":{
        "field":"suggest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect to have both documents in my results, but I only get the second one (nazareth) back:

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "suggest": {
    "suggest": [
      {
        "text": "nazare",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 6,
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "nazaresu",
            "_index": "cities",
            "_type": "cities",
            "_id": "1085-city",
            "_score": 1809.0,
            "_source": {
              "doctype": "city",
              "suggest": {
                "input": [
                  "nazareth",
                  "nazaret",
                  "拿撒勒",
                  "na sa le",
                  "sa le",
                  "le",
                  "na-sa-lei",
                  "나사렛",
                  "nasares",
                  "nasales",
                  "ナザレス",
                  "nazaresu",
                  "नज़ारेथ",
                  "nj'aareth",
                  "aareth",
                  "najaratha",
                  "Назарет",
                  "Ναζαρέτ",
                  "názáret",
                  "nazaretas"
                ],
                "weight": 1809
              },
              "weight": 3015,
              "city": {
                "id": 1085,
                "name": {
                  "en": "Nazareth",
                  "it": "Nazareth"
                },
                "slug": {
                  "en": "nazareth",
                  "it": "nazareth"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is unexpected, because in the suggester input for the first document, the term that I searched "nazare" appears exactly as I input it.

Another fun fact is that if I search for "najare" instead of "nazare" I get the correct results.

Any hint will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a quick solution, use the `size` parameter in the `completion` object of your query.

```
GET /cities/_search
{
  "suggest":{
    "suggest":{
      "prefix":"nazare",
      "completion":{
        "field":"suggest",
        "size": 100             <- HERE
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The size parameter default to 5, so once elasticsearch as found **5 terms** (and not document) having the correct prefix, it will stop looking for more terms (and consequently documents).

**This limit is per term, not per document**. So if one document contains 5 terms having the correct and you use the default value of 5, then possibly the other documents will not be returned.

I strongly believe that it is whats happening in your case. The returned document has at least 5 suggest terms having the prefix `nazare` so only this one will be returned.

For your fun fact, when you are searching `najare`, there is only one term having the correct prefix, so you have the correct result.

The tricky thing is that **the results depends on the order elasticsearch  retrieve the documents**. If the first document would have been retrieved first, it would not have reach the `size` threshold (only 2 or 3 prefix occurrences), the next document would be also retrieved and you would have get the correct result.

Also, unless necessary, avoid using a very high value (e.g. > 1000) for the `size`parameter. It might impact the performance particularly for short or common prefixes.